# Unable to get correct file format from uploaded files

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my code.When I click `save` after uploading a document am splitting the file formats.

- when I upload images,I will get this `data:image/jpeg`.
- when I upload pdf, I will get this `data:application/pdf`.

Here am facing one issue,when I upload `.txt` files am getting `data:text/plain` .

why don't I get `data:text/txt`.

Similarly for `docs/docx/xls` it returns like this `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
   
    $scope.saveDetails = function(doc) { 
         console.log(doc.file)   
            doc.type = doc.file.split(';')[0]
        console.log(doc.type)
    };
})
app.directive("fileread", [function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            fileread: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
            element.bind("change", function (changeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (loadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.fileread = loadEvent.target.result;
                    });
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(changeEvent.target.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" ng-init="init()">
    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file"  fileread="doc.file"/>
    <button ng-click="saveDetails(doc)">save</button>
</div>
```

what is the issue here & why am I not getting correct extension for `txt/docs/docx/xls`?

Comment: What `doc.file` return to you ?

Comment: If I upload doc file ,it returns `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: ok you why you use `split(';')`? where is `;` in your response?

Comment: sorry If I upload word document I will get full document in `doc.file`.after spliting only i will get `data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordproce‌​ssingml.document`

Comment: see the bottom answer please

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `split` the type again with `:`

if our `data` is as follow:

```
var data = "data:type;test"

//first split the `;`
var ext = data.split(";")[0];

//next split `:` from ext to get the type
var type = ext.split(":")[1];
```